# Memory question in javascript

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, instance

Every time you instantiate a object or a function, does it store memory or is just variables with primitive values that are stored.

For Example - `var myArray = new Array();` or `var num = function(){};`

Answer (score 6):

When you do

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

You create an object in memory and store a *reference* to that object in the `myArray` variable. (A reference is like a pointer in C/C++. It's a value that tells the JavaScript engine where the object is.) E.g.:

```
+−−−−−−−−−+           
| myArray |           
+−−−−−−−−−+           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
|   ref   |−−−−−−−−−−>| instance of an array       |
+−−−−−−−−−+           +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                      | length = 0                 |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

When you do:

```
var n = 2;
```

You store the actual value 2 in `n`:

```
+−−−−−−−−−+
|    n    |
+−−−−−−−−−+
|    2    |
+−−−−−−−−−+
```

This is the essential difference between primitive and object types. (It gets a bit blurred with strings, but you can pretend that primitive strings in JavaScript act just like numbers and such, the engine hides some details from you.)

This is an important distinction, because JavaScript is a purely *pass by value* language, so when you call a function and pass arguments into it, the *values*, not the variables, are passed. Consider:

```
function foo(index, a) {
    return a[index];
}
```

The `foo` function accepts an index and an array, and returns the value of the element in the array at that index.

```
x = foo(n, myArray);
```

That calls the `foo` function and passes in the *value* of `n` (2) and the *value* of `myArray` (a reference to an array). And so `index` receives the same value `n` has (2), and `a` receives the same value `myArray` has (a reference to an array). Since the value in the case of `a` and `myArray` is a reference to an array, they both *refer to* the same array:

```
+−−−−−−−−−+
| myArray |
+−−−−−−−−−+
|   ref   |−−−−−−−+    
+−−−−−−−−−+       |    
                  |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−+       +−−−>| instance of an array       |
|    a    |       |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−+       |    | length = 0                 |
|   ref   |−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
+−−−−−−−−−+

+−−−−−−−−−+
|    n    |
+−−−−−−−−−+
|    2    |
+−−−−−−−−−+

+−−−−−−−−−+
|  index  |
+−−−−−−−−−+
|    2    |
+−−−−−−−−−+
```

The same is true of assignment statements, and for the same reason: The variable on the left of the `=` receives the *value* of the expression on the right of it.

```
var n2 = n;
var a2 = myArray;
```

`n2` receives the value of `n` (2), and `a2` receives the value of `myArray` (a reference to the array). If we diagrammed `myArray`, `a2`, `n`, and `n2`, the diagram would be identical to the one above for `foo`'s arguments `index` and `a`.

Since `myArray` and `a` point to the same array (reference the same object), if they perform *mutator* operations on the array, the results are visible via either reference. For example, adding a new element to the array is a mutator operation, it *changes* the object in place:

```
alert(myArray.length); // 0
alert(a.length);       // 0
a.push("test");
alert(myArray.length); // 1
alert(a.length);       // 1
```

It's important to understand what happened there. The *variables* `myArray` and `a` have not been changed, but the object they refer to has. In contrast:

```
a = someOtherArray;
```

Now `a` is pointing off somewhere else entirely, its *value* is no longer the same as the value of `myArray`, and so it isn't referring to the same object.

---

**Off-topic**: A better way to write

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

is

```
var myArray = [];
```

The end result is the same (a new array is created and assigned to `myArray`), but the second one is shorter, slightly more efficient, and guarantees you'll get an array (whereas the first one *could*, in an unusual situation, not give you an array — if someone has [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `Array` symbol).

Similarly, you can write

```
var obj = new Object();
```

like this

```
var obj = {};
```

...which has similar benefits for the same reasons.

Comment: how come every time you make a change to one reference of a array it does not make a change on another.

Comment: @James: If you actually change the *reference* (e.g., `a = someOtherArray`), then there's no effect on `myArray` because `a` and `myArray` have no link to each other, any more than `n` and `index` have a link to each other and so assigning to `index` doesn't change `n`. However, if you do something that changes the *object* that `a` points to, since `a` and `myArray` both point to the same object, you see that change regardless of what reference you use to get to the object. I've added a bit at the end about that.

Answer (score 2):

every piece of data is stored in a memory. when instantiating and object the object reference is stored in a variable. when using primitive types the actual value is stored in a variable.

Comment: what is a reference to a object stored as

Comment: It's a memory address where the object resides.

Comment: when you past data through an object,call a method, or call a property is that data stored in the variable.    Example - myarray =[4,6,5]

Answer (score 0):

A variable *is* a piece of memory. Anything you can put data into, including functions, uses memory. Without memory, you can't run or use what you've declared before, because you would have forgotten it.

I'm inclined to think that the specifics of how much memory is used and how is implementation-specific, which is why we see the many different performance comparisons. Since V8 and Rhino are open source implementations of Javascript interpreters used in Chrome and Firefox respectively, go check them out if you want to find out the specifics.